# Comparison (<), output (<<) and assignment (=) for boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

I have a few questions about how `boost::optional` works. Let's first do this:

```
boost::optional<int> i;
```

1. Is `i < 3` always equivalent to `*i < 3` (and similar for other relational operators)?
2. Is it correct that the conditions `i < 3` and `*i < 3` are undefined? (`i` has still not been set to anything)
3. What is `std::cout << i` supposed to print?
4. I'm pretty sure that `i = 3` is always the same as `*i = 3`. If so, which should I prefer?

Comment: `i.get()` is your bro.

Comment: did boost dropped its documentation in the late versions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. No. If `i` is uninitialized, the first will return true while the second will assert.
2. No. The documentation for `operator<` clearly indicates that if the lefthand argument is uninitialized it will return `true` when the righthand operand is set.
3. There is no `operator<<` for `optional` so I assume it will return the `unspecified-bool-type` conversion and print 1 or 0 (true/false).
4. They aren't the same. If `i` isn't initialized the latter will assert while the former will initialize-and-assign. You should use the one that indicates the semantics you desire.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding point 3, there **is** an operator<< for boost::optional declared in boost/optional/optional_io.hpp, but you probably aren't including that.  (If you happen to use boost property_tree it gets included for you, though.)  If it is included, an empty optional will stream as "--" and a populated optional will stream out an extra space character and then stream the value.

So this code:

```
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
boost::optional<string> var1 = "value";
boost::optional<string> var2;
cout << " var1 = '" << var1 << "'\n";
cout << "*var1 = '" << *var1 << "'\n";
cout << " var2 = '" << var2 << "'\n";
```

yields this:

```
 var1 = ' value'
*var1 = 'value'
 var2 = '--'
```

but the same code without the include yields this, as suggested by Mark B's answer:

```
 var1 = '1'
*var1 = 'value'
 var2 = '0'
```

That extra space in the first case has caused me some confusion.